# I am facing problem while deploying my django app in vercel

Tags: django, deployment, vercel

**Error**
`WARN! Due to` builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings

> Installing Builder: @ardnt/vercel-python-wsgi
> Starting build
> Build AMI version: Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
> ERROR Invalid runtime configured (python3.6). Available runtimes:
> ERROR  - python3.9
> ERROR See Vercel runtime documentation for more information:
> ERROR https://github.com/vercel/vercel/blob/main/DEVELOPING_A_RUNTIME.md#lambdaruntime
> Error: Invalid runtime configured (python3.6).
> Deployment completed
> : Invalid runtime configured (python3.6).
> `**vercel.json**`{
> "builds": [{
> "src": "Portfolio/wsgi.py",
> "use": "@vercel/python",
> "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
> }],
> "routes": [
> {
> "src": "/(.*)",
> "dest": "Portfolio/wsgi.py"
> }
> ]
> }`

**wsgi.py**
`import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Portfolio.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

app = application`

Comment: I presume it has something to do with this: https://vercel.com/changelog/python-3-6-is-being-deprecated - try using a newer Python version!

Comment: But I am using python3.11.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, I had a similar issue and I fixed it by changing my 'vercel.json' file (Create this if you don't have it btw) to dictate the runtime, so it doesn't default to an outdated preset, As shown below. Also, notice the line `"use": "@vercel/python` it sets the python version to 3.9 as of writing this, and that fixes the issue

```
{
"builds": [{
    "src": "your-app-name/wsgi.py",
    "use": "@vercel/python"
}],
"routes": [
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "your-app-name/wsgi.py"
    }
]
```

}